# Hangfire support - How good is the support?

Tags: hangfire

We are looking to evaluate/acquire the Hangfire product using their commercial license option. I am interested to hear from existing users about how responsive is the Hangfire customer support. Any concerns?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Worked for two corporations in the past that used Hangfire. The larger one (+- 2 years ago) purchased a licence and always received great support.

Looking back the only/main reason we purchased the licence was to make use of a Redis server.

The smaller corp used the public/free version and even under a huge load we never had any issues.

I would absolutely recommend Hangfire, but my suggestion would be to try out the public/free version first before buying the licence.

In other words if you dont need to use a Redis server or any of the additional ['Pro' features](https://www.hangfire.io/pro/#hangfireproredis) then I see no need to purchase Hangfire Pro.